# Using top rows by values_count in pandas again in another sorting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
city     price
Moscow  | 100 
Paris   | 200 
Moscow  | 150 
Lisboa  | 200 
Rome    | 100 
Rome    | 175 
Moscow  | 300 
Rome    | 450 
Paris   | 500 
Istanbul| 430
Milan   | 200
Istanbul| 550
Berlin  | 300
Lisboa  | 500
Rome    | 200
```

I have a dataframe with many columns, but now I use only this two in example.

I need to get top 5 city by count and I get this by

```
data['city'].value_counts().head(5)
```

And I see something like this:

```
Rome    | 4
Moscow  | 3
Paris   | 2
Lisboa  | 2
Istanbul| 2
```

And then, I need to sort same top-5 cities by price and get mean/median for them.

If I use

```
data.groupby('city')['price'].agg(
['mean', 'median', 'count']
).sort_values('mean', ascending=False).head(10)
```

I get list with another cities sorted by 'price' column, but top 5 cities from previous code part won't save.

```
         mean
Istanbul| 450    
Paris   | 350
Lisboa  | 350
Berlin  | 300
Moscow  | 250
```

My question is: is it possible to sort previously created value_counts.head(5) part of dataframe by another column (in my case 'price' column)?

I tried to save it in variable, like

```
s = data['city'].value_counts().head(5)
```

But it's Series and have only city and count value and does not have price values from original dataframe and I stucked. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: don't try to save it in a variable. try to save it in a separate data frame? that might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC try [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) + [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html#pandas-dataframe-nlargest):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'city': {0: 'Moscow', 1: 'Paris', 2: 'Moscow', 3: 'Lisboa', 4: 'Rome',
             5: 'Rome', 6: 'Moscow', 7: 'Rome', 8: 'Paris', 9: 'Istanbul',
             10: 'Milan', 11: 'Istanbul', 12: 'Berlin', 13: 'Lisboa',
             14: 'Rome'},
    'price': {0: 100, 1: 200, 2: 150, 3: 200, 4: 100, 5: 175, 6: 300, 7: 450,
              8: 500, 9: 130, 10: 200, 11: 150, 12: 300, 13: 500, 14: 200}
})

df = (
    df.groupby('city')
        .agg({'city': 'count', 'price': ['mean', 'median']})
        .droplevel(0, axis=1)
        .nlargest(5, 'count')
        .reset_index()
)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
       city  count        mean  median
0      Rome      4  231.250000   187.5
1    Moscow      3  183.333333   150.0
2  Istanbul      2  140.000000   140.0
3    Lisboa      2  350.000000   350.0
4     Paris      2  350.000000   350.0
```

---

Or merge on the results from value_counts something like:

```
s = df['city'].value_counts().head(5).reset_index(name='count')

new_df = df.merge(s.rename(columns={'index': 'city'}), on='city')
print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
        city  price  count
0     Moscow    100      3
1     Moscow    150      3
2     Moscow    300      3
3      Paris    200      2
4      Paris    500      2
5     Lisboa    200      2
6     Lisboa    500      2
7       Rome    100      4
8       Rome    175      4
9       Rome    450      4
10      Rome    200      4
11  Istanbul    130      2
12  Istanbul    150      2
```

Then do whatever operations:

```
new_df = (
    new_df.groupby(['city', 'count'])['price'].mean()
        .reset_index()
        .sort_values('count', ascending=False)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

`new_df`:

```
       city  count       price
0      Rome      4  231.250000
1    Moscow      3  183.333333
2  Istanbul      2  140.000000
3    Lisboa      2  350.000000
4     Paris      2  350.000000
```

Comment: Henry, thanks for your answer! I'm newbie here, so I can't upvote yet, but thank you! It works very good, but is it possible to sort the same top 5 cities by count (I mean Rome,  Moscow, Istanbul, Lisboa and Paris) not in order of a count, but in order of a price?

I mean, we're talking about the same top 5 cities by count, but sort them by a different column, price for now, when Lisboa and Paris take place on top because of the mean price, and Istanbul will be the 5th with the value 140.00?

Comment: Upd. I figured it out. 
I've changed 'count' in sort_values to 'price' and it worked as I wanted! Thanks again!